# Word VBA for Extracting Multiple Word Document Names

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to alter the following Word VBA. Currently as it is, it prompts the user to provide a folder path, then upon receiving the path creates a new word document. It then opens all the word documents in the folder specified and extracts all hyperlinked text into the new Word document it created. Ex:

Hyperlink 1
Hyperlink 2
Hyperlink 3

My goal is to have the VBA not only produce the hyperlinks as shown, but also for the macro to list each document the link is pulled from by title. Ex:

Document 1 - Hyperlink 1
Document 1 - Hyperlink 2
Document 2 - Hyperlink 1
Document 2 - Hyperlink 2

```
Sub ExtractHyperlinksFromMultiDoc()
  Dim objDoc As Document, objNewDoc As Document
  Dim objHyperlink As Hyperlink
  Dim strFile As String, strFolder As String
 
  '  Initialization
  Set objNewDoc = Documents.Add
  strFolder = InputBox("Enter folder path here: ", "Folder path")
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\" & "*.docx", vbNormal)
 
  '  Open each file in the folder to extract hyperlinks and past them to a new document.
  While strFile <> ""
    Set objDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
 
    With objDoc
      For Each objHyperlink In .Hyperlinks
        objHyperlink.Range.Copy
        objNewDoc.Activate
        With Selection
          .Paste
          .InsertParagraph
          .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End With
        Next objHyperlink
    End With
    objDoc.Close
    strFile = Dir()
  Wend
End Sub
```

I have tried to get the VBA to add the file name using this code:
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="FILENAME  \p ", PreserveFormatting:=True

However, all I have managed to get it to add the name of is the new active document the links are currently being extracted onto, instead of the name of the files the links are coming from. All other methods I have tried result in errors.

Comment: You need to specify the document, e.g. Text:=ObjDoc.Name & "\p"

Comment: Thank you for responding freeflow! I tried to specify the document using the code as suggested and received the following error "Error! Bookmark not defined." Any advice on what might be causing that? I should note that the file name doesn't have to be a field and can just be plain text if that simplifies anything.

Comment: Wait, after fiddling with it I managed to get it to work. Thank you!